# Болеть - полисемия или омонимия?

Tags: недопустимая-метка, омонимы

Болеть - полисемия или омонимия?

> Бабушка, ты болеешь?
>   Да, внучок.
>   А за кого: за «Спартак» или за
>   «Динамо»?

болеть - быть больным

болеть - переживать за участника соревнований.

Я думала что это полисемия но ведь бывают же полные омонимы у которых совпадает вся система форм.
Так что же это?

Answer (score 2):

В примере, который Вы приводите, шутка основа на полисемии: второе значение, как можно убедиться,открыв толковый словарь любого языка,переносное. Между ними присутствует тесная связь. Омонимия же основана на двух разных значениях графически/лексически одинаковых слов. Иначе говоря, семантически эти слова друг с другом не связаны. В словаре омонимы даются отдельной статьей, вслед за основным значением слова римской или арабской цифрой.

Answer (score 0):

Как раз связи-то нет. *Болеть - быть больным* и *болеть - поддерживать участника* не связаны. Это омонимия.

Comment: Прежде чем давать подобный ответ, потрудились бы заглянуть в словарь. Слово ''болеть'' в смысле ''быть болельщиком'' употребляется в переносном значении, следовательно, это не самостоятельное слово. Между ними есть связь.

Comment: _Серж: Прежде чем давать подобный ответ, потрудились бы заглянуть в словарь. Слово ''болеть'' в смысле ''быть болельщиком'' употребляется в переносном значении, следовательно, это не самостоятельное слово._ ===  Серж, **словарей-то много**. В какой именно Вы советовали заглянуть  Rupert? И посмотрели ли Вы перед тем, как критиковать Rupert, словарь Ефремовой (http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/efremova/142844 )? В своём ответе Вы написали: _В словаре омонимы даются отдельной статьей, вслед за основным значением слова римской или арабской цифрой._ А разве у Ефремовой не так? См.: значение **III**.

Comment: Посмотрите словарь Ожегова, Викисловарь,

Comment: 1Быть больным.
2.Испытывать боль в каком-либо органе, в части тела.
3перен. Испытывать тревогу, беспокоиться о ком-либо, чем-либо
4перен. разг. Остро переживать успехи и неудачи спортивной  команды или отдельного спортсмена.Толковый словарь Ефремовой. Слава, как видите, противоречивые показания. Надо ориентироваться на бумажный ее словарь. Кстати,у Кузнецова тоже полисемия.

Comment: Rupert, это очень сложный вопрос на самом деле, считать ли значения одного слова, возникшие  как переносные, омонимами или сохранять историческое понимание.  Разные школы трактуют по разному. Поэтому не стоит кидаться  однозначными выводами. Словарями, впрочем, тоже не стоит кидаться.

Answer (score 0):

> Бабушка, ты болеешь?
>
> Да, внучок.
>
> А за кого: за «Спартак» или за «Динамо»?
>
> **Болеть - полисемия или омонимия?**

Розенталь, Голуб и Теленкова в книге "Современный русский язык" приводят три способа разграничения омонимии и многозначности: лексический, морфемный и семантический. При этом замечают:

> Нередки разночтения в определении границ омонимии и многозначности,
>   что сказывается на толковании некоторых слов в словарях… Так, в
>   «Словаре русского языка» С.И. Ожегова слова ***положить*** —
>   «поместить что-либо, где-либо, куда- либо» и ***положить*** — «решить,
>   постановить» даются как омонимы, а в «Словаре современного русского
>   языка» (МАС) — как многозначные.

То же можно было бы сказать и о слове ***болеть***. Несмотря на то, что большинство словаристов ***болеть*** «быть больным» и **болеть** *«быть болельщиком»* считают разными значениями одного слова, Ефремова, похоже, не согласна с таким мнением.

См. её **"Толковый словарь омонимов русского языка"** (М., 2007):

> **БОЛЕТЬ (1)** *несов. непер.*
>   1. Быть больным.
>   2. *перен. разг.* Испытывать тревогу, беспокоиться о ком-л. или о чём-л.
>
> **БОЛЕТЬ (2)** *несов. непер.*
>   1. Испытывать боль в каком-л. органе, в какой-л. части тела.
>
> **БОЛЕТЬ (3)** *несов. непер.*
>   1. Остро переживать успехи и неудачи спортивной команды или отдельного спортсмена.

Так всё же

> **Болеть - полисемия или омонимия?**

Скорее не "или… или", а что-то от полисемии, что-то -- от омонимии. Какая-то степень омонимности здесь вне всякого сомнения присутствует.

У слов *болеть* со значениями «быть больным» и «быть болельщиком» общее происхождение (от слова *боль*), одинаковость форм...  При этом значения их уж очень различны, общих синонимов эти слова, по-моему, не имеют.

Ну а какой из критериев разграничения омонимии и многозначности более весом? А кто его знает.

*"Методология описания и методика различения омографов всё ещё не могут считаться достаточно разработанными"* (Ефремова).

Comment: Слава, а это вы сами(часть пр глагол "болеть" )написали или взяли из книги? В толковом словаре Ефремой за 1989 г. полисемия. Повторю: ориентируйтесь не на интернет-словарь, а на бумажное издание. Я могу вам привести опровержение из того же интернет-словаря Ефремовой. Так или иначе БОЛЬ - физическая или душевная - переживание за кого-то.. болею тобою.. ( жизнь,любовь, боль, мука.) Переносное значение.

Comment: Если у вас есть бумажный словарь, приведите пример из него.

Comment: _Серж: Повторю: ориентируйтесь не на интернет-словарь, а на бумажное издание._ === Тьфу ты... Серж, с чего Вы взяли, что **"Толковый словарь омонимов русского языка"** Ефремовой я взял из Интернета? В Интернете этот словарь  мне найти не удалось (если Вы поможете мне там его найти, буду Вам очень благодарен), съездил в Ленинку, заказал этот словарь, переписал из него статьи с БОЛЕТЬ слово в слово. Думаю, что и  Вы, если у Вас будет большое желание, в какой-либо из библиотек сумеете найти этот словарь. Напомню его название: _"Толковый словарь **омонимов** русского языка"_.

Comment: Похожа, Ефремова толком сама не определилась с этим глаголам. То у нее омонимия, то полисемия.

Comment: Слава, я невнимательно прочитал. Я думал, это толковый словарь.

Comment: У нас в библиотеках этот словарь не будет. Но вот в магазинах можно поискать.